# Redux-saga multiple saga in root saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Here is my code:

**login.saga.ts**

```js
export function* authenticate(action: AuthenticateRequestAction) {
  ...
}

export function* logout(action: LogoutRequestAction) {
  try {
    yield LoginService.logout(action.data);
    yield put(AppActions.resetUser());
    yield put(loginActions.setAuthenticationSuccessRequest(false));
  } catch (err) {
    Notification({
      type: 'error',
      message: err.message,
      description: i18n.t('login.logoutFailed'),
    });
  }
}

export default function* loginSaga() {
  yield [
    takeLatest(ELoginActionTypes.AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST, authenticate),
    takeLatest(ELoginActionTypes.LOGOUT_REQUEST, logout),
  ];
}
```

**rootSaga.ts**

```js
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([appSaga(), loginSaga()]);
}
```

My app is just listening to the first action called, for example **LOGOUT_REQUEST** but won't listen other actions after that one, even the actions called with

```
yield put()
```

So I guess my setup is wrong, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Should you not try something like [this example](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/FutureActions.html) from the redux-saga docs?

```
export default function* loginSaga() {
  while (true) {
    const authAction = yield take(ELoginActionTypes.AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST);
    yield* authenticate(authAction);
    const logoutAction = yield take(ELoginActionTypes.LOGOUT_REQUEST),
    yield* logout(logoutAction);
  };
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the cleanest way to do it, how do you pass params to authenticate() for example ? I guess this is possible the way I'm trying to do it but can't achieve it

Comment: You could pass arguments to authenticate when you invoke it, no? See my edit above.

Comment: Well that seems to do the job thx ! Isn't there a shorter way to do this stuff than writing 2 lignes for each function ?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Why do you want it to be more concise than this?

Comment: Because I feel like it could be less painful

Comment: If my code goes into a catch block, this won't work anymore, starting again to be stuck to the first event send

Comment: Sounds like you are referring to some code that we can't see yet.  Perhaps you should add more to your example above.

Comment: You can see catch block in that code, if something is caught it'll kill sagas

Comment: What is `Notification`?  Why don't you use the `call` effect with that?

Comment: I found the problem, it was in the other file, a saga was calling itself causing an infinite loop

Comment: Ok, you might also want to look at [this page](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RootSaga.html) for a better root saga pattern.  Has this all answered your original question?

Comment: That’s the way I implemented it after the problem was solved but thank you